# get smallest Date after own date from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get smallest date from Dates array after my own Date .
example :

```
var datesArray = ['2019, 10, 4', '2019, 10, 13', '2019, 10, 8', '2019, 10, 6'];
ownDate = '2019, 10, 05';
```

I want to get smallest date after `2019, 10, 05` from `datesArray`. In this example, the answer is: `2019, 10, 06`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the array to get all the dates that are bigger than the one you want, then sort it and get the first one :

```js
var datesArray = ["2019, 10, 4", "2019, 10, 13", "2019, 10, 8", "2019, 10, 6"];
var ownDate = "2019, 10, 05";

var result = datesArray
  .filter(e => new Date(e) - new Date(ownDate) > 0)
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));

var date = result[0];

console.log(date);
```

Comment: Using these values in `new Date()` might lead to different results with different implementations, since these are not standard date formats, so one JS engine might decide to treat them differently to another.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**  Corrected previous code and explanation

```
    var datesArray = ['2019, 10, 4', '2019, 10, 13', '2019, 10, 8', '2019, 10, 6'];
    ownDate = '2019, 10, 05';
    ownDate = convertToDate(ownDate);
    index = -1;
    let maxDate = new Date(8640000000000000);
    function getSmallestDate(){

        for(i = 0;i<datesArray.length;i++){
            convertedDate = convertToDate(datesArray[i]);
            if(convertedDate > ownDate)
            {   
                 if(convertedDate < maxDate)         
                 {
                    maxDate = convertedDate;
                    index = i;
                 }
            }
        }
      if(index != -1)
        console.log(datesArray[index]);
    }

    function convertToDate(dateString)
    {

        dateString = dateString.replace(/,/,'-')
        dateString = new Date(dateString)
        return dateString
    }

    getSmallestDate()
```

- You can have a `running minimum script` which is greater than your owndate, which is exactly what I have done in the above code
- Converting the string to same format and sending to Date() method and then doing normal comparison.

Comment: There is a mistake in this, which I am correcting now. I misunderstood the question.